# Store result of a multi-line Athena query in a variable

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am using https://github.com/finklabs/jupyter-athena-sql to query Athena from Jupyter Lab. I need to store the result of a multi-line query in a variable. I can do this for a single-line query as follows:

```
pd = %athena select 1
pd
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to access the result of a multi-line query, such as this:

```
%%athena 
select col1, count(*)
from my_table
group by col1
```

[In the implementation of the Athena extension](https://github.com/finklabs/jupyter-athena-sql/blob/develop/athena/magic.py#L55) I can see that it's returning a dataframe and I wonder if there is a standard variable in Jupyter Lab that it gets bound to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking up and calling the magic function that's registered to execute Athena queries in the jupyter-athena-sql extension as follows:

```
athena = get_ipython().find_cell_magic('athena')

df = athena("""select col1, count(*)
from my_table
group by col1""")
```